# bash: yt-dlp: command not found, yt-dlp is not on PATH

Tags: bash

When I try to download with yt-dlp I get this error message from terminal of Ubuntu

```
bash: yt-dlp: command not found
```

I use this command to install yt-dlp

```
python3 -m pip install -U yt-dlp
```

and after I get this message

```
WARNING: The scripts mid3cp, mid3iconv, mid3v2, moggsplit, mutagen-inspect and mutagen-pony are installed in '/home/appbox/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  WARNING: The script yt-dlp is installed in '/home/appbox/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
```

How can I solve and add `yt-dlp` and `mid3cp`, `mid3iconv`, `mid3v2`, `moggsplit`, `mutagen-inspect` and `mutagen-pony` on PATH ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
editor ~/.bashrc
```

Search for declaration of PATH variable (or create it), then:

```
export PATH=~/.local/bin:$PATH
```